# Multiple reanimated2 animations on same component in React native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have a card component with 2 buttons present inside it '**Follow**' and '**Dismiss**'. If I press on '**Dismiss**' I want the component to do a fade-out-up animation and when I press '**Follow**' the component should do a fade-out-left animation.

Can someone help me with how to do this in React native using re-animated library?